# No ethernet connection: "ip configuration was unavailable"

Tags: kubuntu, ethernet, ip, wired

[image]

Hello all,

I've been having a problem for some time now and without any solution.
I've used to use the ethernet connection on my linux Kubuntu 18.04, but since some time ago i can't connect to it.
I've searched and tryed multiple online solutions, but without any luck.
The ethernet hardware is OK and working (i've tested it with other computers)

The following are some outpus that migth help catching the problem:

```
**sudo ifconfig**

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 
       ether 4c:cc:6a:30:ad:db  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet) 
       RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B) 
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0 
       TX packets 209  bytes 34933 (34.9 KB) 
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0 
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536 
       inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0 
       inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host> 
       loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback) 
       RX packets 2192  bytes 218766 (218.7 KB) 
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0 
       TX packets 2192  bytes 218766 (218.7 KB) 
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0 
wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 
       inet 192.168.1.77  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255 
       inet6 fe80::af01:70b1:3e87:1345  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link> 
       inet6 2001:8a0:e3c5:1000:e8ec:e215:a11d:8b20  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global> 
       inet6 2001:8a0:e3c5:1000:16e2:613f:e17a:2207  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global> 
       ether 34:97:f6:63:13:c7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet) 
       RX packets 77112  bytes 20588483 (20.5 MB) 
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0 
       TX packets 162279  bytes 229023638 (229.0 MB) 
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
**sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf**

# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search Home
```

```
**sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces**

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

All files are as they are original installed.

Thank you all for you help.

Comment: Have you set a network configuration in netplan or Network Manager? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: No i haven't come across that solution yet. Can you give me some guide on how to properly do it to see if it works?

Comment: Ideally, netplan should *not* be changed in a desktop installation. Verify: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Also, Netwrork Manager, if modified by you might lead to errors. The NM GUI should look like this: https://i.postimg.cc/MZ3JD71Y/Screenshot-from-2020-10-22-12-42-51.png If, for example, you tried to set a static IP address and it's in the wrong network, you will never connect. Please revert to automatic everything if this has been changed.

Comment: you can use this command to start your ethernet connection:  sudo modprobe "insert the name of your ethernet driver here"  and don't use the quotes. It should start right away. If it does, then you would have to make it permanent (but I don't know enough to tell you how).

Comment: First of all thaks for the help, i will post here both solutions that you guys presented, but none is working so far (i am new to linux):

Comment: :~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml 
 # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system 
 network: 
 version: 2 
 renderer: NetworkManager 
:~$ sudo lspci 
 ...
 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controll
 er (rev 15) 
 03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe  Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: :~$ sudo modprobe rtl8111 
 modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8111 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0- 52-generic 
:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8168 
 modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8168 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0- 52-generic 
:~$ sudo modprobe RTL8168 
 modprobe: FATAL: Module RTL8168 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0- 52-generic

Comment: What did you find in Network Manager? What does this tell us? `sudo dhclient enp2s0`?

Comment: Network Manager was as default, all automatic (i am using Kubunto 18.04 by the way).

Comment: When i type "sudo dhclient enp2s0" nothig happens. I've never used this command before, and after clicking Enter to execute it just stays with the cursor on the bottom line. i've waited 10mints to see if it was time related, but still nothing.

Comment: Just a noob solution that worked for me (I have no idea why the wired connection refused to connect suddenly, because it worked 45 minutes earlier). I've created new wired connection via GUI, let myself have a static IP (adjusted router accordingly, of course) and gave the connection higher autoconnect prio than the default wired connection had. No idea why but it worked. Hopefully for good xD